# Typescript extending class a from class b. But not getting all class a's functions

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I've stumbled upon a problem i haven't quite encountered yet.
I'm using sequelize as an orm in typescript and i made an user entity. The user entity extends sequelize's class "Model" that holds all the crud related functions.
When i try to call the crud functions in class a (the entity class) it works fine. Intelisense in webstorm also picks them up in code completion.

When i try it in class b that extends class a however the functions are not found or undefined.

Can anyone show some light on what i'm doing wrong?

Class A:

```
import sequelizeDatabase from "../sequelize/sequelize";
import {
    DataTypes, Model, Optional
} from "sequelize";

export interface UserAttributes {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    password: string,
    rank: number,
    status: number,
    plan: number
}

export interface UserInput extends Optional<UserAttributes, "id">{}
export interface UserOutput extends Required<UserAttributes>{}

export class UserEntity extends Model<UserAttributes, UserInput> {
    declare id: number;
    declare name: string;
    declare password: string;
    declare rank: number;
    declare status: number;
    declare plan: number

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public async init() {
        UserEntity.init({
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(75),
            },
            password: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
            },
            rank: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED
            },
            status: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED
            },
            plan: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(25)
            }
        }, {
            sequelize: sequelizeDatabase,
            freezeTableName: true,
            timestamps: false
        })
        UserEntity.sync().then(r => {
            console.log("UserEntity synced")
        })
    }
}
UserEntity.create() //found
```

Class B:

```
import {
    UserEntity, UserInput,
    UserOutput, UserAttributes
} from "./UserEntity";

class User extends UserEntity {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public async add(payload: Partial<UserAttributes>): Promise<UserOutput> {
        this.create() //not found
    }
}
```

Comment: as I can see in your code a create is a class-level method. so it is not available in the instance of the class.

Comment: You should be using `User.create`, not `this.create`.